# Enable Timer after the page is loaded

Tags: c#, gridview, timer, updatepanel

I've a Web app and use an UpdatePanel and Timer to refresh GridView data. I set the Timer interval to 10000. When the page loads, it takes 10000 milliseconds to display the GridView data from the database server. How can I disable the Timer when the page loads and enable it after the page is loaded? In other words, the data should be displayed right away after the page is loaded. I appreciate any pointers.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DisplayResultsUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="DisplayResultsGridView" AllowSorting="true" gridlines="Vertical" OnSorting="DisplayResultsGridView_Sorting" onrowdatabound="DisplayResultsGridView_RowDataBound" runat="server" > 
            </asp:GridView>   
        </div>  

         <asp:Timer ID="DisplayResultsTimer" Interval="10000" Enabled="true" runat="server" OnTick="DisplayResultsTimer_Tick">    
            </asp:Timer>  
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void DisplayResultsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageRefreshAsOf.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement a loadcomplete Event as it is described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.ASPX

```
<asp:Page OnLoadComplete="EventHandler" />
```

For furhter documentation of Events refer to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I finally found the problem. I passed the wrong parameter to the data access method. That's why the data are not displayed immediately after the page is loaded.